# Microsoft Outlook: "Your server administrator has limited the number of items you can open simultaneously" -> how can I how many items I have open?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook-2013

I use Microsoft Outlook 2013 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

I was trying to accept a meeting invitation on Microsoft outlook and got this message:

> Your server administrator has limited the number of items you can open simultaneously. Try closing messages you have opened or removing attachments and images from unsent messages you are composing.

[image]

which appeared when I clicked on:

[image]

How can I count how many items I have open? It's unclear to me what counts as "opened items".

Comment: Do you have any shared mailbox added in your current Outlook profile? Is cached Exchange mode enabled for the shared mailbox?

Comment: @SteveFan I have 2 shared mailboxes added in my current Outlook profile, and cached Exchange mode is enabled for them.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this and/or find a solution?  :)  - ta

Comment: @ChrisKimpton No. Luckily, it doesn't occur too frequently those days. Also, I try to stay away from the Microsoft Outlook desktop client as much as I can (too slow and buggy).

Answer (score 1):

This problem may occur because Outlook 2010 and later versions locally caches (in your Outlook data file [.ost]) all folders to which you have access in the secondary mailbox. To resolve this problem, use one of the following methods:

Method 1: Reduce the number of folders in the Shared mailbox

Method 2: Disable caching of all shared folders

Method 3: Change the configuration of the secondary Exchange mailbox to a second Exchange account in your profile

You may choose the proper method for your situation. See this Microsoft official KB article for details:

[Performance and synchronization problems when you work with folders in a secondary mailbox in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/3115602/performance-and-synchronization-problems-when-you-work-with-folders-in)